# Declare methods dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a model and want to declare functions for all attributes on it.

Let's say these are the attributes: [firstName, lastName]

I want to be able to get them with:

```
person.firstName()
person.lastName()
```

How do I define methods programmatically from an array of strings?

Comment: Is `person` a singleton or do you have multiple such objects?

Comment: I have multiple persons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
['firstName', 'lastName'].forEach(function(funcName) {
    var prop = person[funcName];    
    person[funcName] = function() {
        return prop;
    }
});
```

[CodePad](http://ideone.com/s6PQX).

If you didn't know the properties in advance, you could use `Object.keys()` if the environment supports it, or use a `for ( in )` loop to get the keys.

[CodePad](http://ideone.com/B9blK).

Comment: I don't know the properties in advance so your second solution fits. Really great answer, thanks!